# Ignite clear() method is throwing exception with Version 2.15.0

Tags: ignite

The Ignite `clear()` which was working with 2.11.0 is now throwing below exception. There aren't any config changes.

```
javax.cache.CacheException: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Remote job threw exception.
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheUtils.convertToCacheException(GridCacheUtils.java:1272)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.cacheException(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:2084)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.clearAll(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:1654)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.clearAll(GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.java:1202)
    at geode.casper.ignite.CasperIgniteHelper.clearAllByKeys(CasperIgniteHelper.java:107)
    at geode.tme.cache.TMECache.internalClearCacheItems(TMECache.java:86)
    at geode.tme.cache.CacheManager.clearCacheItems(CacheManager.java:58)
    at geode.tme.flatfile.task.ClearCacheTask.execute(ClearCacheTask.java:39)
    at geode.services.scheduler.task.Task.executeTask(Task.java:435)
    at geode.services.scheduler.task.Task.execute(Task.java:369)
    at geode.services.scheduler.process.Process.executeTasksNow(Process.java:287)
    at geode.services.scheduler.process.Process.executeTasks(Process.java:210)
    at geode.services.scheduler.process.Process.executeTasks(Process.java:197)
    at geode.services.scheduler.SchedulerServiceImpl$2.run(SchedulerServiceImpl.java:243)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Remote job threw exception.
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.cast(IgniteUtils.java:7929)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.resolve(GridFutureAdapter.java:261)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get0(GridFutureAdapter.java:173)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get(GridFutureAdapter.java:142)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.clear(GridCacheAdapter.java:1147)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.clearAll(GridCacheAdapter.java:1118)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.clearAll(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:1651)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Remote job threw exception.
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$ClearTask.result(GridCacheAdapter.java:7174)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker$4.apply(GridTaskWorker.java:1071)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker$4.apply(GridTaskWorker.java:1064)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.wrapThreadLoader(IgniteUtils.java:7463)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.result(GridTaskWorker.java:1064)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.onResponse(GridTaskWorker.java:868)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.processDelayedResponses(GridTaskWorker.java:716)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.body(GridTaskWorker.java:539)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:125)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor.startTask(GridTaskProcessor.java:753)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor.execute(GridTaskProcessor.java:448)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.executeClearTask(GridCacheAdapter.java:1172)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to send message to remote node: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=a064e16f-0b64-43a7-a687-abcbb7887e2f, consistentId=a064e16f-0b64-43a7-a687-abcbb7887e2f, addrs=ArrayList [127.0.0.1, 172.17.0.2], sockAddrs=null, discPort=0, order=5, intOrder=5, lastExchangeTime=1694434475703, loc=false, ver=2.15.0#20230425-sha1:f98f7f35, isClient=true]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage0(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:1152)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:1052)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.send(GridIoManager.java:2102)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.sendToGridTopic(GridIoManager.java:2195)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.sendRequest(GridTaskWorker.java:1450)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.processMappedJobs(GridTaskWorker.java:669)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.body(GridTaskWorker.java:533)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: No session found
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.GridNioServerWrapper.createNioSession(GridNioServerWrapper.java:660)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.GridNioServerWrapper.createTcpClient(GridNioServerWrapper.java:693)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createTcpClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:1181)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.GridNioServerWrapper.createTcpClient(GridNioServerWrapper.java:691)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.ConnectionClientPool.createCommunicationClient(ConnectionClientPool.java:442)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.ConnectionClientPool.reserveClient(ConnectionClientPool.java:231)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage0(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:1105)
```

Upgraded Ignite Version from 2.11.0 to 2.15.0 and clear method is throwing exception. Need solution on why `Ignite.clear()` is throwing exception.

Comment: Can you share some more information about your cluster? Configuration? Number of nodes? Cache configuration? Number of records being cleared? I don't see this problem on my cluster.

Comment: We've 3 clusters and 9 nodes .  We're trying to clear around 87K records .

Comment: Is it a full stack trace? I have a suspicion that it's somewhat cut.

Comment: @Vladimir Pligin - Full stack trace is posted now .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be specific to version 2.15.0 . We have downgraded the version to 2.14.0 which is working fine in Prod .

Comment: I ran into same issue again . -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true solved the problem momentarily , its not permanent solution . Any help here would be appreciated.